# How to add a new table/column to an existing table using mysql for a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am developing an API only application in rails 5 with MySQL. Can I add a new column to an existing table or new table directly in MySQL database instead of using rail generator(rails generate migration add_email_to_users email:string / rails generate model User)?

If yes, how to create migration for this?

Comment: Please accept the answer that works for you @OmarAlhadidy https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You should do this by executing migrations.
```

But, if you want directly , then you can execute the `alter table` statement in the mysql.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD email varchar(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the ALTER command

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD email VARCHAR(60);
```

This first statement will add the email column to the end of the table. To insert the new column after a specific column, such as name, use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD email VARCHAR(60) AFTER name;
```

If you want the new column to be first, use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD email VARCHAR(60) FIRST;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in rails console:

```
$ rails c
> ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column :users, :email, :string
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Must Help You**

```
statement = "Your SQL statement HERE"
```

Then execute your SQL statement as:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     connection.execute(statement)
end
```